# How do i call a Stored Procedure and fetch it's resaults from the Model

Tags: database, vb.net, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013

I have been following [This lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/DevCampTraining/blob/master/02.Setting%20up%20the%20Environments/hands-on-lab.md#Exercise4) but i did 2 things differently

1. I am using VB not C#
2. I used my local Database rather than Azure

i completed the lab and it all works correctly. from here i planned to experiment on my completed lab by doing things i would expect to be doing at work, one such thing is using a stored procedure to update a record from the form submitting

Currently i ma planning on updating the CustomerController for editing to that when i submit the form this procedure runs

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[alterCustomerName]
    @ID INT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE Customers
    SET FirstName = 'test'
    FROM Customers
    WHERE ID = @ID

    SELECT 2 AS 'output'

END
```

I updated the Model to include the Stored Procedure but i can't seem to work out how to call it from the Model, when i [google search it](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=vb%20sharepoint%20call%20stored%20procedure&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=X6VSVYDBB8HwmAXgwoG4DA), even with adding sharepoint to the criteria i get the general method of calling SQL Queries in VB, nothing pertaining to using the Model created when developing a Sharepoint App.

While i could just do that i get the feeling there a way to call it similar to

```
db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified
db.SaveChanges()
```

which is found in the Edit Function.

So **How can i call my stored procedure using the Model and fetch it's result?**

EDIT: i have worked out i can call the procedure just be doing `db.[Procedure]` but i can't seem to get the data from the final select. current i use this line of code

```
Dim resault = db.alterCustomerName(customer.ID)
MsgBox(resault)
```

when i run that i get a message box with -1 outputted. when i place a dot at the end i can't find any function which would allow me to select the output field in my select.

Comment: This is not relevant to SharePoint and it is more of a Database programming question so i would suggest to tag/post it accordingly.

Comment: @kesava i have tagged it appropriately at least to the tags i can think of which apply to the question which i can find. i am quite sure it is still on-topic as per the [the help topic's](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) second list, first point saying *"Programming using the SharePoint web services or object model"* which is what i am asking, using the Model that has been by VB in my Sharepoint App Project to call a procedure.

Comment: if this question however is off-topic and i am mistaken in my understanding of the list of on-topic items then i would like to request a Moderator to migrate it to Stack Overflow. i asked it here figuring there would be more specialized SharePoint Developers

Comment: Thanks for explaining this with a link to help topic's. I wanted to make it clear that "Programming using the SharePoint web services or object model" belongs to SharePoint object model which is a dedicated programming language (earlier WSS 3.0) with SharePoint specific objects supported in .Net framework and Refer this : [Refer here] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms430674%28v=office.12%29.aspx) where as the one you have mentioned is about the ASP.Net MVC framework or design pattern in which model is a link b/w controller and view.